# django in virtaul environment giving ImportError

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, django-1.7

if i run

```
(My_Virtual_Env) G:\My-Project\My_Code>python ..\My_Virtual_Env\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject My_django_project
```

its working fine and new project is getting created.

But when i run

```
(My_Virtual_Env) G:\My-Project\My_Code>django-admin.py startproject My_django_project
```

am getting error

ImportError: No module named django.core

i want to know why it is happening ? and what are the changes need to do to run second command as it is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `My_Virtual_Env/Scripts` folder is not added to the classpath by default. That is why you get that error. If you install django, the directory of this will directly be added to classpath. Why do you execute from another place?

Comment: Thanks #Ashwin, but i was executing it from another place because i wanted to put my whole project in separate directory.

Comment: @MahendraVishwakarma Django admin file should not be a part of your project anyways. You will always have it installed along with django.